# Calculating Predicition Interval in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, statistics, prediction, normal-distribution

Just for clarification: I am **NOT** looking for a *CONFIDENCE* interval.

I have been looking for a way to calculate a `Predicition Interval` based on my dataset,
Assuming a `Normal Distribution`, so far I have only been able to find usages of confidence intervals. Does anyone have any references or know of built in functions?

(for example's sake:)

```
9 entries: 52,54,54,57,58,59,64,70,72

µ = 60, s^2 = 51.25, s = 7.159

Expected answer: (60 – 2,31 * 7,159 √(1+ 1/9) , 60 + 2,31 * 7,159 √(1+ 1/9)) = (42.6 , 77.4)
```

EDIT: I realized my example used a t-distribution but I hope the point is clear enough.

Comment: What significance does 2.31 have to your data set?

Comment: the 2.31 value is read from the t-distribution table with n=8 and (1-alpha)= 0.975

Comment: I present the following with a healthy dose of "I am not a statistician", but the wikipedia article for prediction interval says that the formula is [μ-zσ, μ+zσ] with z being a z score. For a given set, the mean and standard deviation are easily calculated with `AVG()` and `STDEV()`, so it would seem that you just need to pick a z score and you're golden. What am I missing?